# Operational semantics for throwing exceptions to other threads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, semantics

I've read ["Tackling the Awkward Squad"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/mark.pdf?from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fmarktoberdorf%2Fmark.pdf) paper by SPJ and most of it was quite easy to follow however I didn't completely understand what exactly those two conditions above the separation line mean:

[image: throwTo semantics]

In paper it is stated that they are here to ensure that the second context (E2) is maximal, i.e. it includes all the active catches. However I do not completely understand what it means. Does it mean that an exception won't be thrown if there is a `catch` inside of a second thread? But why is bind also there then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, it is used to "insert" the exception `ioError e` in the right place, in a deterministic way.

Consider `M = catch (threadDelay 1000000) someHandler`. We have both:

```
M = Ea[M]
   where Ea[x] = x
M = Eb[M']
   where Eb[x] = catch x someHandler
         M' = threadDelay 1000000
```

without the side condition, we would have two distinct operational steps, making the semantics non-deterministic:

```
{throwTo t e}s | {M}t ==> {return ()}s | {Ea[ioError e]}t
                        = {return ()}s | {ioError e}t
{throwTo t e}s | {M}t ==> {return ()}s | {Eb[ioError e]}t
                        = {return ()}s | {catch (ioError e) someHandler}t
```

In the former case, the error is not caught, in the latter it is. The side condition ensures only the latter is a valid step.

Bind is there as well to avoid replacing everything in:

```
M = catch (threadDelay 1000000) someHandler >>= something
```

Here, if you only require "`M` not a catch", you could again choose `M = Ea[M]` and replace all the code. The side condition instead forces you to choose

```
Ec[x] = catch x someHandler >>= something
```

and insert the `ioError e` in the correct place inside the `catch`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! I had to re-read the definition of an evaluation context to finally understand it: An evaluation context must fill the hole with a term, a value is a term, and `M >>= N` is a value, hence we need to make sure we don't replace that.